# ActiveRecord default value if attribute is nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Looking for a cleaner way to set a default value if attribute is not set yet or has been deleted, and returns nil.

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :restaurants
  belongs_to :picture

  def set_picture
    if self.picture.nil?
      Picture.default_pic
    else
      self.picture
    end
  end
end

class Picture < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :review

  def self.default_pic
    Picture.new(url: "/assets/default.jpg")
  end
end

# index.html.erb
<%= image_tag category.set_picture.url %>
```

categories has many restaurants, and restaurants has many reviews. Reviews has one to one picture. category should be allowed to select from one of its associated pictures, or defaults to image in assets folder.

The #set_picture needs to get refactored out. Hopefully to a callback of some type:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :picture, defaults_to: Picture.default_pic
end
```

Is there a callback that does the above? Can I create one? Or is my framework wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you could just override the accessor and call super. If this returns nil then you could return your default picture:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :picture

  def picture
    super || Picture.default_pic
  end 
end
```